# Why my auto click tool doesnt work when clicking?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AutoClickerC
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        #region dlls
        [DllImport("User32.Dll", EntryPoint = "PostMessageA")]
        private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);


        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys vKey);

        #endregion
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void btnToggle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnToggle.Text.Contains("enable"))
            {
                btnToggle.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(80, 80, 80);
                btnToggle.FillColor = Color.Salmon;
                btnToggle.Text = "disable";
            }
            else if (btnToggle.Text.Contains("disable"))
            {
                btnToggle.ForeColor = Color.Salmon;
                btnToggle.FillColor = Color.FromArgb(80, 80, 80);
                btnToggle.Text = "enable";
            }
        }

        private void btnToggle_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnToggle.Text.Contains("disable"))
            {
                Autoclicker.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                Autoclicker.Stop();
            }
        }

        private void lbvalueC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void tbToggle_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            CPSValue.Text = (CPSTrackabr.Value.ToString() + " CPS");
        }


        int min;
        int max;
        IntPtr hWnd;
        public string getActiveWindowName()
        {
            try
            {
                var activateHandle = GetForegroundWindow();

                Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
                foreach (Process clsProcess in processes)
                {
                    if (activateHandle == clsProcess.MainWindowHandle)
                    {
                        string processName = clsProcess.ProcessName;
                        return processName;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }
            return null;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnToggle.Text.Contains("disable"))
            {
                min = CPSTrackabr.Value - 6;
                max = CPSTrackabr.Value + 6;
                Random rand = new Random();
                randomTB.Value = (rand.Next(min, max));
            }
        }
    

        private async void AutoClicker_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
            Autoclicker.Interval = 1000 / randomTB.Value;
            }
            catch { }
            if (btnToggle.Text.Contains("disable"))
            {
                Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("javaw");
                foreach (Process process in processes)
                {
                    hWnd = FindWindow(null, process.MainWindowTitle);
                }

                string currentwindow = getActiveWindowName();
                if (currentwindow == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (currentwindow.Contains("javaw"))
                {
                    if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
                    {
                        PostMessage(hWnd, 0x0201, 0, 0);
                        await Task.Delay(30);
                        PostMessage(hWnd, 0x0202, 0, 0);
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I Dont know why its doesnt work, i'm learning to make auto click tool. My code like the example on ytb but its doesnt work, everything is okay, except auto click still doesnt work. Did im wrong somewhere? I mean, im tried so many tutorial on ytb, but until final part, auto click still not working in spite of some part still working. Im coding on VS community 2022, windowform .NET FrameWork and aslo using laptop acer nitro 5 with windows 11.Need somehelp, im hopeless now :(

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-do-you-simulate-mouse-click-in-c There are solutions that dont use PostMessage but actually trigger a mouse click.

Comment: I just posted a full working example of an AutoClick on my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74732714/5438626) to a similar question and in addition to Felix' link you can also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10355905/5438626).